# How to change color of an router-link on mouse over inside the style component?

Tags: css, vue.js

Currently I have this inside the **App.vue** file style component:

```
#nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #1eb2a6;
    }
  }
}
```

It is not clear how to add here the hover event so I can change the text color of the button.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to change the text color on hover.

```
#nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
    &:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```